# What is the value of the regularized incomplete beta function at x=0.5?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory

What is $I_{0.5}(a,b)$ where I is the regularized incomplete beta function?

Comment: Could you please give us a reference to the definition of $I$?

Comment: You can get your answer yourself from http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html.

Comment: There's no $I_{0.5}$ there :-(

Comment: @Neil: I'd join Robin and recommend you to decipher your $I_{0.5}(a,b)$ by giving an integral or series expression. Otherwise it sounds like you are not interested in getting an answer.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.  $I$ is defined here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RegularizedBetaFunction.html

but there is no expression for $I_0.5$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function
$$
\frac{\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} t^{a - 1} (1 - t)^{b - 1} d t}{\int_{0}^{1} t^{a - 1} (1 - t)^{b - 1} d t} =  \\
\quad{}\quad{}\frac{\mathrm{hypergeom} \Bigl([a,-b + 1],[1 + a],\frac{1}{2}\Bigr) \Gamma (a + b)}{2^{a} a \Gamma (b) \Gamma (a)}
$$
Why do you think there is anything simpler in general?

Comment: Thanks, Gerald, for demystefying the piece! Yes, there is no reduction of the $_2F_1$ hypergeometric series for general $a$ and $b$. But there are other ways to write it hypergeometrically.

Comment: I thought there would be something simpler because when a and b are natural numbers, the function yields a natural number.

Comment: But, thank you for your answer...

Comment: (...yields a *rational* number)